# Eigenvalue problem- (Fourier Collocation Method)

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, eigenfunctions

I have an eigenvalue problem $$
\mathbf{L} \Psi=\lambda \Psi,
$$
where
$$
\mathbf{L}=i\left(\begin{array}{cc}
G_0 & \nabla^2+G_1 \\
\nabla^2+G_2 & -G_0
\end{array}\right), \quad \Psi=\left(\begin{array}{c}
v \\
w
\end{array}\right),
$$
$\nabla$ means $\frac{d}{dx}$. I expand the eigenfunction $\Psi$ as well as the functions $G_0, G_1$ and $G_2$ into Fourier series. So, the eigenvalue problem turns into a matrix eigenvalue problem for   the Fourier coefficients of the eigenfunction $\Psi$ on the interval $x\in[-L/2,L/2]$. Let's assume Fourier series are \begin{gathered}
v(x)=\sum_n a_n e^{i n k_0 x}, \quad w(x)=\sum_n b_n e^{i n k_0 x}, \\
G_p=\sum_n c_n^{(p)} e^{i n k_0 x}, \quad p=0,1,2,  
\end{gathered}
where $k_0=2\pi/L$. When we substitute these expansions into the eigenvalue problem we get the following equations
\begin{aligned}
\sum_n c_n^{(0)} a_{j-n}-\left(k_0 j\right)^2 b_j+\sum_n c_n^{(1)} b_{j-n} & =-i \lambda a_j, \\
-\left(k_0 j\right)^2 a_j+\sum_n c_n^{(2)} a_{j-n}-\sum_n c_n^{(0)} b_{j-n} & =-i \lambda b_j,
\end{aligned}
where $j,n \in [-N,N]$.

(*Yang, Jianke*, [**Nonlinear waves in integrable and nonintegrable systems.**](https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9780898719680), Mathematical Modeling and Computation 16. Philadelphia, PA: Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics (SIAM) p. (2010).)

My question: What if we had $G_0 \nabla$ in $L(1,1)$ and $L(2,2)$ instead $G_0$? I mean, if we had the eigenvalue problem:
$$
\mathbf{L}=i\left(\begin{array}{cc}
G_0 \nabla  & \nabla^2+G_1 \\
\nabla^2+G_2 & -G_0 \nabla
\end{array}\right), \quad \Psi=\left(\begin{array}{c}
v \\
w
\end{array}\right),
$$
then, would the equations above be like
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_n c_n^{(0)}. i(j-n)k_0 .a_{j-n}-\left(k_0 j\right)^2 b_j+\sum_n c_n^{(1)} b_{j-n}  =-i \lambda a_j, \\
&-\left(k_0 j\right)^2 a_j+\sum_n c_n^{(2)} a_{j-n}-\sum_n c_n^{(0)}.i(j-n). b_{j-n}  =-i \lambda b_j
\end{aligned}
?